# multi language html page

Tags: html, web

The website I'm currently working on is supposed to be in multiple languages (4 in this case).
What's the "best" way to achieve this?

It seems like most people use a php table for it. Is this the "best" way right now?

Alas I only know some HTML and CSS, so my idea was to simply copy the whole website tree and make a seperate html tree for each language starting with index.html as the default language and three other trees starting with index_lang2.html, index_lang3.html, index_4.html.

On the index site you could switch the language and go down each seperate html tree.
Is this solution acceptable? I seems quite easy to generate but hard to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it depends on how much pages you have! There is no reason in making a language system if you only have 10 plain html pages and have no clue about php. And such systems are *"only for"* UI Elements and not for the real **content** if you plan to post information there...
If that are static pages, then using no such system is a nice solution!

But if you have more, then there are several solutions:

1. Take an existing Framework with language support
2. Write your own language class with vars on the different places
3. ... there are for sure more possibilities, but nothing which comes in my mind :)

Comment: There are 7 different pages with most of the content + about 70 more for the image gallery, which has way less text content. In this case my proposed solution with different trees would be fine?

Comment: @BlueHorizon i would make this 7 pages static as you described and for the image gallery use a downloadable gallery. Just google for that. (e.g. i googled http://codex.gallery2.org/Gallery3:Features which supports many languages)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I find the [Supersized gallery](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) to be better to show off lots of high quality pictures :).

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, I think as long as your site only has limited static HTML webpages then it's not worth trying to implement a fancy PHP solution (especially if you have to learn PHP to do so!)